# How to toggle control between view form and the Edit form in the infopath?

Tags: infopath

I have control or field in my InfoPath form which I need to hide it when I view the item (view form) and show when I Edit an item (Edit form) in SharePoint 2013. Is there any way I can achieve this? I believe it is doable between new form and view form. Please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Page Design tab, create one Edit form and one View form

Let the Edit form be the default form.

Then click File > Form Options > Web Browser. In the Display View drop-down select the View form.

When the form is opened for viewing, the "View" page will be used. When opened for Editing, the default "Edit" page will be used.